# WSO2 ESB who called me

Tags: wso2-esb

I built a generic FAUF sequence which generates messages in case of processing problems and draws attention of people in the service Desk.
To make the troubleshooting easier, I want to provide a full trace "who called" my error sequence, as the generic FAUF sequence is used on many places.
Example:
Proxy Service 1 -> Sequence 1 -> Sequence 2 -> **FAUF occured**.
Any idea how to read out this information?

thank you very much for your suggestions in advance.
regards,
jan

Answer (score 0):

For the proxy name you can use something like this:

```
<log level="custom"> 
    <property name="proxyName" expression="$ctx:proxy.name"/>
</log>
```

In the case of the sequence name, you can create a property in every sequence, for example:

```
<property name="sequenceName" value="Sequence 1"/>
```

And get the value inside a log mediator in the fault sequence

```
<log level="custom"> 
    <property name="SequenceName" expression="get-property('sequenceName')"/>
</log>
```

Comment: thank you, do you happen to also know how can I learn who called my sequence?

Comment: your sequences can be called by another sequence or by a proxy service so, you just need to put this mediador before setting the sequence name in the current sequence: <log level="custom"> 
    <property name="proxyName" expression="$ctx:proxy.name"/>
    <property name="SequenceName" expression="get-property('sequenceName')"/>
</log>

Comment: if my answer work for you please mark it as the right one.